# How do I create multiple views for different users by role?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a User that can have multiple roles `player`, `coach`, `guest`.

I want to have different views of a `player_profile (profile/8)` depending on the user that is logged in or viewing that profile.

Aside from writing a bunch of `if` statements in my views to detect `cancancan` permissions, is there a simpler/more sane way to tackle this in as DRY as fashion as possible?

Comment: Depends on how different the views are.  If there are few differences, then branching on abilities is fine, but if the views are radically different, you can branch on roles/abilities in the controller method and render different views.

Comment: @MarsAtomic Some are slightly different, but I am more concerned about the ones that are drastically different. Can you show me an example of branching in the controller plz. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display different views based on user role, you can employ some simple branching logic in the controller. Let's take the `show` action as an example:

```
def show
  if current_user.role == 'admin'
    render 'show_admin'
  else
    render 'show'
  end
end
```

This example assumes that you have access to a `current_user` helper, either from something like Devise or your own solution, a `show_admin.html.erb file`, a `show.html.erb` file and a `role` attribute on your `User` model.

There isn't really that much to it.

Comment: Or you can simply make use of partial

Comment: @Deepak Care to illustrate?

Comment: @Deepak The reason there's no example of a partial is because OP specifically requested sample code for "drastically different" views. A partial implies that that the views are mostly the same other than what's in the partial.

Answer (score 4):

You can render the view dynamically base on the user's role:

```
def show
  render "show_#{current_user.role}"
end
```

This will render `show_admin`, `show_guest`, `show_xxx` base on the current_user's role. But it requires that you create all these views and be aware when you add a new role in the future that can access thi route.

If the above will be a problem, there is a way to check if the view exists before rendering:

```
lookup_context.exists?(dynamic_template_name)
```

You can create a method to handle it:

```
def show
  render view_for_user(:show)
end

private

# This will render `show_guest` if not user is logged in. Otherwise it will 
# checks if the requested view exists or show a default one (view_name)

def view_for_user(view_name)
  return "#{view_name}_guest" unless current_user

  dynamic_template_name = "#{view_name}_#{current_user.role}"

  lookup_context.exists?(dynamic_template_name) ? dynamic_template_name : view_name
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting potential answer. Thanks for this!